# Visual Basic/Excel: How to select a relative cell?

Tags: excel, visual-studio

In a macro I'm recording, I want it to select the second cell in a row (the B column).

So if A7 is selected, the macro will select A2,
if H4 is selected, the macro will select H2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column).Select
End Sub
```

or to select column **2**

```
Sub qwerty()
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This selects the second row in the selected column. I want to select the second column in the selected row. How do I need to change your answer to do this?

Comment: @user3075190 That is different from your original request and example.  But I see Gary's Student has already responded.

Answer (score -1):

You need a worksheet event. Not tested but should go in right direciton

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column < 2 Then
   Range(Target.Column.Offset(0,1)).Select
Elseif Target.Column > 2 Then
   Range(Target.Offset(0,2-Target.Column)).Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is absoutely no way there is enough information here to answer this question. There's no language tag and for some reason it's tagged with [tag:visual-studio].